limit memory usage of python processes
I have Server written in Python / FastAPI + Gunicorn running for a prolonged periods of time. After a couple of hours we are noticing some peaks in memory consumption that we haven't been able to resolve for a long time! These peaks are quiet short in time lasting only a couple of ms. They may involve the creation of large as np.ndarray (a couple hundreds of MBs).
I am trying to figure out a way to improve the visibility of the memory usage of the programs when these memory peaks allocations happen. So I came across this article that discusses a very simple solution (using the resource module)
I tried to do a POC with it before trying it in the actual server.
The idea is simple:

put a memory limit (say 1MB)
try to allocate memory (descending / ascending between 1MB and 0MB)
The expected result is a value close to the limit passed to the arguments (990KB for example)

import resource
import sys
import numpy as np

import resource

import resource

def format_b(n_bytes):
    """ Format a number of bytes into a human-readable format. """
    for unit in ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB']:
        if n_bytes < 1024:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (n_bytes, unit)
        n_bytes /= 1024
    return "%.1f %s" % (n_bytes, 'EB')

def set_memory_limit_as(n_bytes):
    _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (n_bytes, hard))
    print("Setting memory limit to", format_b(n_bytes))

def set_memory_limit_rss(n_bytes):
    _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS)
    print("Setting RSS memory limit to", format_b(n_bytes))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS, (n_bytes, hard))

def set_memory_limit_data(n_bytes):
    _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA)
    print("Setting heap memory limit to", format_b(n_bytes))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA, (n_bytes, hard))

def set_memory_limit_memlock(n_bytes):
    _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_MEMLOCK)
    print("Setting virtual memory limit to", format_b(n_bytes))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, (n_bytes, hard))

def set_memory_limit_stack(n_bytes):
    _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK)
    print("Setting virtual memory limit to", format_b(n_bytes))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (n_bytes, hard))    

mem_limit = int(sys.argv[1])
set_memory_limit_as(mem_limit)  # try to change this function and re-run the script with 1MB

size = mem_limit * 2
prev_size = 0


try:
    bla = np.random.randint(0, 255,size=(1 * size,), dtype=np.uint8)
    bla += 1
except MemoryError:
    print("Memory errors occurs for mem_limit:" , format_b(size))
    print("expected")
else:
    print("Memory errors did not occur for mem_limit:" , format_b(size))
    print("unexpected")
    exit(1)

# use dichotomy to find the highest value between size and prev_size that does not raise a MemoryError
while size - prev_size > 1_000:  # a difference of 1KB
    new_size = (size + prev_size) // 2
    print("trying mem_limit:" , format_b(new_size))
    try:
        bla = np.zeros(1* new_size, dtype=np.uint8)
        print("Memory errors did not occur for mem_limit:" , format_b(new_size))
    except MemoryError:
        print("Memory errors occurs for mem_limit:" , format_b(new_size))
        size = new_size
    else:
        prev_size = new_size
 
print("Memory limit is around:" , format_b(prev_size))

Sadly it doesn't behave as expected, whatever the memory limit I use.
Here is the output I am getting on my ubuntu 22:
$ python memory-limit.py 1_000_000 # with RLIMIT_AS
Setting memory limit to 976.6 KB
Memory errors occurs for mem_limit: 1.9 MB
expected
trying mem_limit: 976.6 KB
Memory errors occurs for mem_limit: 976.6 KB
...
Memory limit is around: 61.0 KB
$ python memory-limit.py 1_000_000  # with RLIMIT_RSS                                                                              
Setting RSS memory limit to 976.6 KB
Memory errors did not occur for mem_limit: 1.9 MB
unexpected
$ python memory-limit.py 1_000_000    # with RLIMIT_DATA                                                                          
Setting heap memory limit to 976.6 KB
Memory errors occurs for mem_limit: 1.9 MB
expected
trying mem_limit: 976.6 KB
...
Memory limit is around: 61.0 KB
$  python memory-limit.py 1_000_000  # withRLIMIT_MEMLOCK                                                                             
Setting virtual memory limit to 976.6 KB
Memory errors did not occur for mem_limit: 1.9 MB
unexpected
$ python memory-limit.py 1_000_000   # with RLIMIT_STACK  of course this is an expected behavior because this is the stack memory that we are limiting!                                                                          
Setting virtual memory limit to 976.6 KB
Memory errors did not occur for mem_limit: 1.9 MB
unexpected

Two things shock me in the experiments above:

for the case of RLIMIT_AS and RLIMIT_DATA, why memory fail to be allocated even though the requested memory is far lower than the limit set (memory_limit is set at 1MB and process fails for 100KB!?)
Why memory allocation succeeds in the case of RLIMIT_RSS set to 1MB and requested memory is 2MB!?

Is there any way to achieve my long sought solution ? Or shall I stay an astray man :D ?
